# Different ways of copy&paste rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to speed up a VBA programm which basically copy rows of data from a couple of workbooks into 3 main workbooks and refresh all the graphics in them.

I have already use this, which I mainly do in all my programms.

```
'Speed up
With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
```

Debugging my code I realised the copy&paste part is taking more time than the rest and I am trying to recode It and test so I can reach the fastest solution. Initially it was like this across 3 differen Subs. I post one because all the others are the mainly de same.

```
Cellsheet.Range("2:" & f2).Copy DataCell.Range((f + 1) & ":" & (f + f2))
DataCluster.Rows((f3 + 1) & ":" & (f3 + f4 - 1)).Hidden = False
Clustersheet.Range("2:" & f4).Copy DataCluster.Range((f3 + 1) & ":" & (f3 + f4 - 1))
```

I am trying to avoid using the clipboard which I know It would be the slowest solution. Now, Im trying the .Value = .Value approach like this:

```
DataCell.Range((f + 1) & ":" & (f + f2)).Value = Cellsheet.Range("2:" & f2).Value
DataCluster.Range((f3 + 1) & ":" & (f3 + f4 - 1)).Value = Clustersheet.Range("2:" & f4).Value
```

*In this example I'm trying to copy 2.000 rows more or less when the error appears.*

The problem is with this approach the programm more or less in the middle of the execution shows the "Insufficient memory error" and I would like to know why this happens and If there is a faster solution than the .Copy Destination. thing.

Comment: Your code is copying entire rows - do you actually use all 16384 columns?

Comment: yowE3K is right try selecting only the used column instead of the entire row

Comment: This command `Sheet2.Range("A1:GZ16000").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:GZ16000").Value` will copy 33,280,000 cell values in about 3-4 seconds. So try and work with explicit ranges and not entire rows.

Comment: similar to getting row numbers get column numbers once....and use range(cells(),cells()) method to copy the values. you dont need to get the column number everytime if you have the same number of column.

Answer (score 1):

Your coding is a horror (@Sivaprasath was more polite, but I try to be more helpful :-)). Make it look like this.

```
DataCell.Range(Cells(R, C), Cells(R, C)).Value = Cellsheet.Range(Cells(R, C), Cells(R, C)).Value
```

Here R stands for a "Row" and C for "Column". Each can be a number or a variable presenting a number. A range like `Range("A1:B4")` would be written like `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 2))` which looks an awful lot of effort in direct comparison but it is more readable than `Range((f + 1) & ":" & (f + f2))` and it is really easy to manipulate, once you get the hang of it. To speed up your task it is vital that you have exact control over your range specifications and that will elude you while you have no clear syntax.

I ran this test in response to your comment.

```
Private Sub CopyAndPaste()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim f As Long, f2 As Long
    Dim C As Long

    f = 4
    f2 = 2046
    C = 185

'    Set Rng = Cellsheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(f2, C))
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(f2, C))
    Debug.Print Rng.Address, Rng.Cells.Count

'    Set Rng = DataCell.Range(Cells((f + 1), 1), Cells(f + f2, C))
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells((f + 1), 1), Cells(f + f2, C))
    Debug.Print Rng.Address, Rng.Cells.Count
End Sub
```

The result is printed to the Immediate window and shows that the number of cells in the two ranges isn't the same. Therefore the two ranges can't be of the same size and dimension, and therefore you should get an error in the past operation. I suggest you invest a little bit more time in controlling your variables. However, using the Destination to copy to it is sufficient to specify a single cell (top left) and Excel will paste the entire copied range correctly in relation to the specified cell.